# Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and application server IBM WebSphere issues

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere

I am using windows 7, an old version of Eclipse,  Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) and WebSphere Application Server Version 8.5.5.9 Liberty.

I am working on a pretty old codebase. Java 1.7 and configuration/library management tools like Maven or Ant is not used here. I used neither eclipse nor WebSphere before. So it is very confusing to me.

The issue is that whatever code, I update it doesn't reflect when try to debug my code. I tried clan build by eclipse as well as manually delete the build directory to make sure it is really clean. Still, my latest code change is not visible after deployed to the WebSphere Application Server. How can I see my latest code changed in the IDE?

**UPDATED Question**

In the WebSphere Application Server installation location there are following directory:-

bin,
clients,
dev,
lafiles,
lib,
templates,
usr

usr dir has subdirectory:-

.settings,
servers,
shared,
.project

Inside the servers directory:-

.classCache,
.logs,
myserver

This myserver directory is copied from one of my colleagues. I was told it is kind of WebSphere Application Server profile.

This myserver has the following subdirectory:-

apps,
config,
dropins,
logs,
resources,
tranlog,
workarea,
jvm.options,
server.env,
server.xml

I deployed the application from eclipse as Run As:- 
Run on Server

The application is deployed at apps directory as Application-HEAD.ear.xml

If I open Application-HEAD.ear.xml file I can read 
All my application submodule path is given there.

If I delete this Application-HEAD.ear.xml, it is generated as soon as I deploy from eclipse. But the problem still exists my code change is not reflected.

Comment: Can you explain, in detail, how it's set up to deploy right now?

Comment: Please check the updated question explanation.

Comment: 1) Is it a requirement that you use Liberty 8559?  Liberty 19007 is free for development and OpenLiberty is plain free.
2) Does Application-HEAD.ear.xml point to the project containing the app source?
2) If you make a change in code and rebuild the project in eclipse, do you see updates on the server console from Liberty indicating the app was redeployed?

Comment: 1. it is not my choice. It is the company is using it. I think it has some hard dependency that we can't move to some other version. 2. Yes, Application-HEAD.ear.xml points to the application source build directories. Please tell me how to check server console? I have no idea at all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use the eclipse Console view if you have the right plugins installed.  A simpler way is to tail the messages.log file in the logs directory you mentioned above.

Comment: How would I log from my application to this server log. To verify my code changes are reflected. I ment System.out.log would show standard output. So how to send to server log to tail that log?

Comment: You can use System.out/err and JUL out of the box for application logging.  If you look at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html, output to System.out/err is by default copied to all logs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebSphere but I'm guessing it's like GlassFish, WildFly, etc. Have you tried explicitly undeploying (not just deleting the file) the war file from WebShpere before doing "Run As > Run on Server"?